# Use multiple URLs with $.getJSON

Tags: jquery, json, variables

I have a few lines of code:

```
var url = 'http://api.spitcast.com/api/spot/forecast/1/';
var url_wind = 'http://api.spitcast.com/api/county/wind/orange-county/';

$.getJSON(url, function (data) {

etc...
```

How would I pull both of these URLs into my $.getJSON command? I thought it would be as simple as:

```
$.getJSON(url, url_wind, function (data) {
```

I have also tried assigning these two URLs to the same variable as such:

```
var url = ['http://api.spitcast.com/api/spot/forecast/1/','http://api.spitcast.com/api/county/wind/orange-county/'];
```

Unfortunately I'm having no luck pulling the info from the second URL.

Could anyone please help me out? Thanks.

Comment: you need to use two different requests

Comment: If you want to collect JSON from two endpoints, you have to make two separate calls.

Comment: One request = One url

Answer (score 25):

You'll need two calls, but you can use `$.when` to tie them to the same `done()` handler :

```
var url = 'http://api.spitcast.com/api/spot/forecast/1/';
var url_wind = 'http://api.spitcast.com/api/county/wind/orange-county/';

$.when(
    $.getJSON(url),
    $.getJSON(url_wind)
).done(function(result1, result2) {

});
```

Comment: Use `result1[0]` to receive the data.

Answer (score 3):

you cannot, use two separate calls:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    $.getJSON(url_wind, function (data2) {
        //do stuff with 'data' and 'data2'
    });    
});
```

Example above will execute the second call (to url_wind) when the first call (to url) has finished. To execute the *two calls in parallel*, use [$.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) like this:

```
$.when($.getJSON(url), $.getJSON(url_wind)).done(function(data1, data2) {
    //do stuff with 'data' and 'data2'
});
```