# GETjson with urls multiples

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I need many GETjson to many URLs in javascript but I have a question, Is posible in only one GETjson use the urls multiples?.

My code now is:

```
               $.getJSON('URL.php', function(data) {

                    $.each(data, function(key, val) {

                       ***CODE***

                    });
            });
   $.getJSON('URL1.php', function(data) {

                    $.each(data, function(key, val) {

                       ***CODE***

                    });
            });
       $.getJSON('URL2.php', function(data) {

                    $.each(data, function(key, val) {

                       ***CODE***

                    });
            });
```

I used the next codes but  don't working:

```
$.getJSON('URL1.php','URL2.php', function(data) {

                    $.each(data, function(key, val) {

                       ***CODE***

                    });
            });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Nice answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20148292/2182349

Answer (score 0):

Put the URLs in an array, and loop through the array.

```
var urls = ['url1.php', 'url2.php', 'url3.php'];
$.each(urls, function() {
    $.getJSON(this, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            // *** CODE ***
        });
    });
});
```