# Javascript - Load arbitrary number of URLS with $.getJson

Tags: javascript

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148239/use-multiple-urls-with-getjson) if I had 2 urls that I wanted to load in parallel and then use the data from I could do it as follows:

```
var url1 = 'some-url';
var url2 = 'some-other-url';

$.when(
    $.getJSON(url1),
    $.getJSON(url2)
).done(function (result1, result2) {
    // code using two results
});
```

How could I generalize this to an arbitrary number of urls, especially a list containing some number of urls? Essentially I would like to take a list of URLs, map the function $.getJSON to each url, and once each url's data has been fetched do thing with the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `$.when` does not take an array of promises/deferreds, you will need to put each promise returned from `$.getJSON()` into an array and either use [.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) on `$.when` or use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) (`...`), if targeting compatible browsers

```
//map each url to a getJSON call
var urls = ["url","url","url"];
var proms = urls.map(url=>$.getJSON(url));
```

**Using .apply()**

```
$.when.apply($,proms).then(function(data1,data2,data3){
   console.log("data: ",data1,data2,data3);
});
```

**Using spread operator (`...`)**

```
$.when(...proms).then(function(...data){
   console.log("data: ",data[0],data[1],data[2]);
});
```

And of course as **pwolaq** mentions in the comments you could just pass the array to [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) as it does take an iterable object of promises

```
Promise.all(proms).then(function(data){
   console.log("data: ",data[0],data[1],data[2]);
});
```

Comment: another way around this is to use array with ES6 Promise.all()

Answer (score 2):

It looks like each `$.getJSON` is a deferred object. You pass these 'promises' to the `when` function to execute them and call back to `done` when they're done.

What we'll do is first map the URLs to promises by passing the `getJSON` function to JavaScript's array `map` higher order function.

Now, we need to call `when` with a dynamic number of arguments. This is where the `apply` function comes in handy. By calling this function with `deferred` as the second argument, JS calls `when(deferred[0], deferred[1], ...)`.

To get the results in the `done` function, we can use the handy `arguments` variable to get the arguments passed to the `done` function dynamically.

```
var urls = ['some-url', 'some-other-url'];

//turn the URLS into promises that we'll get them
var deferred = urls.map($.getJSON);

//make the dynamic call to when
$.when.apply(this, deferred).done(function () { //
    // code using two results
    for(i in arguments) {
         var result = arguments[i];
         //do something with result
    }
});
```

Thanks for the interesting question! This is really where dynamic languages like JavaScript shine.